# Two definite-integrals

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I have two defenite integrals that I know the awnser to, but I need to find a analatic derivation. The integrals are
\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\cos \phi d\phi}{(c-\cos \phi)^2}&=\frac{2\pi}{(c^2-1)^{\frac{3}{2}}}  & \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{d\phi}{(c-\cos \phi)^2} &= \frac{2\pi c}{(c^2-1)^{\frac{3}{2}}}
\end{align}
where $c>1$. Does anyone know a technique to calculate them analytically?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Weierstrass substitution?

Comment: A lot of other dupes, e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1412037/357390) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4099482/357390). Both integrals fall easily to complex analysis.

Comment: Yeah I see, thank you!